# Unable to change Authentication Mode in SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016-express, ssms-2017

I have just installed SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 Express and SSMS 2017 using the **Basic** option from the installation wizard. After installation, I wanted to change the mode of authentication from **Windows Authentication** to **SQL Server Authentication**. I was following the steps given in the link: [Change Server Authentication Mode from docs.Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode#SSMSProcedure). Upon clicking OK after changing the authentication mode, I am getting the following error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Alter failed for Server 'SHASHANK-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?
ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17213.0+((SSMS_Rel).171128-2020)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Alter+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_instance_regwrite', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 229)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.4001&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=229&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you rebooted are you logged back in as sa with the correct password for the sa account?
If you are then try:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_instance_regwrite TO [user]
```

(user being the user you are logged in as).

There was also an answer posted here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1176585-391-1.aspx